# Remove e-mail addresses from the website

Tags: security, email, jsp, owasp

I have a `jsp page` that is `emailaddresses.jsp` where i have written some email addresses of some persons. When a user wants to contact then s/he can use those email addresses, i have no `form` and i am not using any `action`. But when i did security scan then it is telling to `Remove e-mail addresses from the website`. How can i remove these email addresses? How can i fix this problem?

```
emailaddresses.jsp

Email: xyz@gmail.com// email addresses used only for contact
Email: abc@gmail.com
```

Any idea please

Comment: why -1? I cannot remove this email addresses as these are essential

Comment: The security scan is saying it doesn't think you should put the email address on the page, as pages are often scrapped for email address then spam is sent to them. I would presume you can either ignore the warning or use a contact form instead.

Comment: okay i understood, excellent remark Chales

Comment: can you store those addresses in a database and then retrieve using JSP or a servlet?  That should be fairly easy to setup.

Comment: @Zack Macomber: the problem is not that the server can read those addresses (and it still could, if it was able to retrieve them from a database); it is that malicious web clients can read them.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering email addresses in plain text on your web page will result in those emails being harvested and ultimately those mailboxes filling up with spam. I would recommend employing one of the three techniques in this blog post:

http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/

Comment: Like it says in the comments on that site, your safest and most usable bet may be a contact form.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the addresses in an image.

And if you're getting them from a db or similar your could generate the image(s) on the fly in your jsp.

People will have to copy them to use them instead of being able to click on mailto links, but it will prevent simple scraping.